# Can I use useSWR with apollo-client?

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo-client, swr

I'm very new to this all next.js graphQL world.

I just found useSWR and I was wondering if I can use this with Apollo-client,
not with the graphql-request.

Comment: Apollo is not a fetcher, it's a complete graphql client with normalizing cache ... SWR[+fetcher] and Apollo does the same

Comment: why not graphql-request?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, and I do. I have two headless CMSs coexisting. One is headless wordpress bundled with google through OneGraph; the other is Headless Booksy, a closed source CMS with no publicly accessible endpoints -- dissected the network tab during user-driven events to determine any required headers/params and ultimately reverse engineered their auth flow to automate it in my repo using asynch partitioning.

That said, yes, I use apollo Client and SWR in tandem. Here is the _app.tsx config

- _app.tsx

```
import '@/styles/index.css';
import '@/styles/chrome-bug.css';
import 'keen-slider/keen-slider.min.css';

import { AppProps, NextWebVitalsMetric } from 'next/app';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import { useEffect, FC } from 'react';
import { useApollo } from '@/lib/apollo';
import * as gtag from '@/lib/analytics';
import { MediaContextProvider } from '@/lib/artsy-fresnel';
import { Head } from '@/components/Head';
import { GTagPageview } from '@/types/analytics';
import { ManagedGlobalContext } from '@/components/Context';
import { SWRConfig } from 'swr';
import { Provider as NextAuthProvider } from 'next-auth/client';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';
import { fetcher, fetcherGallery } from '@/lib/swr-fetcher';
import { Configuration, Fetcher } from 'swr/dist/types';

type T = typeof fetcher | typeof fetcherGallery;
interface Combined extends Fetcher<T> {}

const Noop: FC = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>;
export default function NextApp({
    Component,
    pageProps
}: AppProps) {
    const apolloClient = useApollo(pageProps);

    const LayoutNoop = (Component as any).LayoutNoop || Noop;

    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
        document.body.classList?.remove('loading');
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleRouteChange = (url: GTagPageview) => {
            gtag.pageview(url);
        };
        router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
        return () => {
            router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
        };
    }, [router.events]);

    return (
        <>
            <SWRConfig
                value={{
                    errorRetryCount: 5,
                    refreshInterval: 43200 * 10,
                    onLoadingSlow: (
                        key: string,
                        config: Readonly<
                            Required<Configuration<any, any, Combined>>
                        >
                    ) => [key, { ...config }]
                }}
            >
                <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
                    <NextAuthProvider session={pageProps.session}>
                        <ManagedGlobalContext>
                            <MediaContextProvider>
                                <Head />
                                <LayoutNoop pageProps={pageProps}>
                                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                                </LayoutNoop>
                            </MediaContextProvider>
                        </ManagedGlobalContext>
                    </NextAuthProvider>
                </ApolloProvider>
            </SWRConfig>
        </>
    );
}
```

Then, I have this api-route handling reviews + pagination of those reviews via SWR in index.tsx

- pages/api/booksy-fetch.ts

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { BooksyReviewFetchResponse } from '@/types/booksy';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';
import { getAccessToken } from '@/lib/booksy';

const API_KEY = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BOOKSY_BIZ_API_KEY ?? '';
const FINGERPRINT =
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BOOKSY_BIZ_X_FINGERPRINT ?? '';

export default async function (
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse<BooksyReviewFetchResponse>
) {

    const {
        query: { reviews_page, reviews_per_page }
    } = req;

    const { access_token } = await getAccessToken();
    const rev_page_number = reviews_page ? reviews_page : 1;
    const reviews_pp = reviews_per_page ? reviews_per_page : 10;

    const response = await fetch(
        `https://us.booksy.com/api/us/2/business_api/me/businesses/481001/reviews/?reviews_page=${rev_page_number}&reviews_per_page=${reviews_pp}`,
        {
            headers: {
                'X-Api-key': API_KEY,
                'X-Access-Token': `${access_token}`,
                'X-fingerprint': FINGERPRINT,
                Authorization: `s-G1-cvdAC4PrQ ${access_token}`,
                'Cache-Control':
                    's-maxage=86400, stale-while-revalidate=43200',
                'User-Agent':
                    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.152 Safari/537.36',
                Connection: 'keep-alive',
                Accept: '*/*',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
            },
            method: 'GET',
            keepalive: true
        }
    );

    const booksyReviews: BooksyReviewFetchResponse =
        await response.json();
    res.setHeader(
        'Cache-Control',
        'public, s-maxage=86400, stale-while-revalidate=43200'
    );

    return res.status(200).json(booksyReviews);
}
```

and the following api route handling image data for a custom marquee also in index.tsx

- pages/api/booksy-images.ts

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { Gallery } from '@/types/index';
import { getLatestBooksyPhotos } from '@/lib/booksy';

export default async function (
    _req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse<Gallery>
) {
    const response: Response = await getLatestBooksyPhotos();
    const booksyImages: Gallery = await response.json();
    res.setHeader(
        'Cache-Control',
        'public, s-maxage=86400, stale-while-revalidate=43200'
    );

    return res.status(200).json(booksyImages);
}
```

Now, to examine index.tsx. I'll break the code into serverside vs clientside for clarity

- index.tsx (getStaticProps -- server)

```
export async function getStaticProps(
    ctx: GetStaticPropsContext
): Promise<
    GetStaticPropsResult<{
        other: LandingDataQuery['other'];
        popular: LandingDataQuery['popular'];
        Places: LandingDataQuery['Places'];
        merchandise: LandingDataQuery['merchandise'];
        businessHours: LandingDataQuery['businessHours'];
        Header: DynamicNavQuery['Header'];
        Footer: DynamicNavQuery['Footer'];
        initDataGallery: Partial<
            Configuration<Gallery, any, Fetcher<Gallery>>
        >;
        initialData: Partial<
            Configuration<
                BooksyReviewFetchResponse,
                any,
                Fetcher<BooksyReviewFetchResponse>
            >
        >;
    }>
> {
    console.log(ctx.params ?? '');
    const apolloClient = initializeApollo();
    const { data: DynamicSlugs } = await apolloClient.query<
        DynamicNavQuery,
        DynamicNavQueryVariables
    >({
        query: DynamicNavDocument,
        variables: {
            idHead: 'Header',
            idTypeHead: WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum.NAME,
            idTypeFoot: WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum.NAME,
            idFoot: 'Footer'
        }
    });
    const { data: LandingData } = await apolloClient.query<
        LandingDataQuery,
        LandingDataQueryVariables
    >({
        query: LandingDataDocument,
        variables: {
            other: WordPress.Services.Other,
            popular: WordPress.Services.Popular,
            path: Google.PlacesPath,
            googleMapsKey: Google.MapsKey
        }
    });
    const { other, popular, Places, businessHours, merchandise } =
        LandingData;
    const { Header, Footer } = DynamicSlugs;
    const dataGallery = await getLatestBooksyPhotos();
    const initDataGallery: Gallery = await dataGallery.json();

    const dataInit = await getLatestBooksyReviews({
        reviewsPerPage: 10,
        pageIndex: 1
    });
    const initialData: BooksyReviewFetchResponse =
        await dataInit.json();
    return addApolloState
        ? addApolloState(apolloClient, {
                props: {
                    Header,
                    Footer,
                    other,
                    popular,
                    Places,
                    businessHours,
                    merchandise
                },
                revalidate: 600
          })
        : {
                props: {
                    initialData,
                    initDataGallery
                },
                revalidate: 600
          };
}
```

notice how returned props can be handled as a function of whether it is SWR vs Apollo Client data? Next is pretty awesome

- Note the functions being called here in getStaticProps

```
    const dataGallery = await getLatestBooksyPhotos();
    const initDataGallery: Gallery = await dataGallery.json();

    const dataInit = await getLatestBooksyReviews({
        reviewsPerPage: 10,
        pageIndex: 1
    });
    const initialData: BooksyReviewFetchResponse =
        await dataInit.json();
```

-- they come from the lib directory. They are meant to be consumed on the server of page files for injecting SWR with initial data. Essentially, it achieves the same means as the api route files but since those are only able to be consumed on the client this is a necessary workaround.

Now for the client

- index.tsx (default export -- client)

```
export default function Index<T extends typeof getStaticProps>({
    other,
    popular,
    Header,
    Footer,
    merchandise,
    Places,
    businessHours,
    initialData,
    initDataGallery
}: InferGetStaticPropsType<T>) {
    const GalleryImageLoader = ({
        src,
        width,
        quality
    }: ImageLoaderProps) => {
        return `${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality || 75}`;
    };
    const reviews_per_page = 10;
    const [reviews_page, set_reviews_page] = useState<number>(1);
    const page = useRef<number>(reviews_page);
    const { data } = useSWR<BooksyReviewFetchResponse>(
        () =>
            `/api/booksy-fetch?reviews_page=${reviews_page}&reviews_per_page=${reviews_per_page}`,
        fetcher,
        initialData
    );
    const { data: galleryData } = useSWR<Gallery>(
        '/api/booksy-images',
        fetcherGallery,
        initDataGallery
    );

    // total items
    const reviewCount = data?.reviews_count ?? reviews_per_page;

    // total pages
    const totalPages =
        (reviewCount / reviews_per_page) % reviews_per_page === 0
            ? reviewCount / reviews_per_page
            : Math.ceil(reviewCount / reviews_per_page);

    // correcting for array indeces starting at 0, not 1
    const currentRangeCorrection =
        reviews_per_page * page.current - (reviews_per_page - 1);

    // current page range end item
    const currentRangeEnd =
        currentRangeCorrection + reviews_per_page - 1 <= reviewCount
            ? currentRangeCorrection + reviews_per_page - 1
            : currentRangeCorrection +
              reviews_per_page -
              (reviewCount % reviews_per_page);

    // current page range start item
    const currentRangeStart =
        page.current === 1
            ? page.current
            : reviews_per_page * page.current - (reviews_per_page - 1);

    const pages = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= reviews_page; i++) {
        pages.push(
            data?.reviews ? (
                <BooksyReviews pageIndex={i} key={i} reviews={data.reviews}>
                    <nav aria-label='Pagination'>
                        <div className='hidden sm:block'>
                            <p className='text-sm text-gray-50'>
                                Showing{' '}
                                <span className='font-medium'>{`${currentRangeStart}`}</span>{' '}
                                to{' '}
                                <span className='font-medium'>{`${currentRangeEnd}`}</span>{' '}
                                of <span className='font-medium'>{reviewCount}</span>{' '}
                                reviews (page:{' '}
                                <span className='font-medium'>{page.current}</span> of{' '}
                                <span className='font-medium'>{totalPages}</span>)
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className='flex-1 inline-flex justify-between sm:justify-center my-auto'>
                            <button
                                disabled={page.current - 1 === 0 ? true : false}
                                onClick={() => set_reviews_page(page.current - 1)}
                                className={cn('landing-page-pagination-btn', {
                                    ' cursor-not-allowed bg-redditSearch':
                                        reviews_page - 1 === 0,
                                    ' cursor-pointer': reviews_page - 1 !== 0
                                })}
                            >
                                Previous
                            </button>

                            <button
                                disabled={page.current === totalPages ? true : false}
                                onClick={() => set_reviews_page(page.current + 1)}
                                className={cn('landing-page-pagination-btn', {
                                    ' cursor-not-allowed bg-redditSearch':
                                        reviews_page === totalPages,
                                    ' cursor-pointer': reviews_page < totalPages
                                })}
                            >
                                Next
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </BooksyReviews>
            ) : (
                <ReviewsSkeleton />
            )
        );
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        (async function Update() {
            return (await page.current) === reviews_page
                ? true
                : set_reviews_page((page.current = reviews_page));
        })();
    }, [page.current, reviews_page]);
    return (
        <>
            <AppLayout
                title={'The Fade Room Inc.'}
                Header={Header}
                Footer={Footer}
            >
                {galleryData?.images ? (
                    <Grid>
                        {galleryData.images
                            .slice(6, 9)
                            .map((img, i) => {
                                <GalleryCard
                                    key={img.image_id}
                                    media={galleryData}
                                    imgProps={{
                                        loader: GalleryImageLoader,
                                        width: i === 0 ? 1080 : 540,
                                        height: i === 0 ? 1080 : 540
                                    }}
                                />;
                            })
                            .reverse()}
                    </Grid>
                ) : (
                    <LoadingSpinner />
                )}
                {galleryData?.images ? (
                    <Marquee variant='secondary'>
                        {galleryData.images
                            .slice(3, 6)
                            .map((img, j) => (
                                <GalleryCard
                                    key={img.image_id}
                                    media={galleryData}
                                    variant='slim'
                                    imgProps={{
                                        loader: GalleryImageLoader,
                                        width: j === 0 ? 320 : 320,
                                        height: j === 0 ? 320 : 320
                                    }}
                                />
                            ))
                            .reverse()}
                    </Marquee>
                ) : (
                    <LoadingSpinner />
                )}
                <LandingCoalesced
                    other={other}
                    popular={popular}
                    places={Places}
                    businessHours={businessHours}
                    merchandise={merchandise}
                >
                    {data?.reviews ? (
                        <>
                            <>{pages[page.current]}</>
                            <span className='hidden'>
                                {
                                    pages[
                                        page.current < totalPages
                                            ? page.current + 1
                                            : page.current - 1
                                    ]
                                }
                            </span>
                        </>
                    ) : (
                        <ReviewsSkeleton />
                    )}
                </LandingCoalesced>
            </AppLayout>
        </>
    );
}
```

There are two useSWR hooks on the landing page:

```
    const { data } = useSWR<BooksyReviewFetchResponse>(
        () =>
            `/api/booksy-fetch?reviews_page=${reviews_page}&reviews_per_page=${reviews_per_page}`,
        fetcher,
        initialData
    );
    const { data: galleryData } = useSWR<Gallery>(
        '/api/booksy-images',
        fetcherGallery,
        initDataGallery
    );
```

the `initialData` and `initDataGallery` values listed after their respective fetchers is the initial data shuttled from the server to the client and inferred via `InferGetStaticPropsType<T>`. This provides a solution to the first load data problem when it comes to client side data fetching.

An additional configuration you can make to expedite fetching of data on the client when using SWR is to specify which api routes should be preloaded in `_document.tsx` and the name of their corresponding fetcher(s)

- _document.tsx

```
                    <link
                        rel='preload'
                        href={`/api/booksy-fetch?reviews_page=1&reviews_per_page=10`}
                        as='fetcher'
                        crossOrigin='anonymous'
                    />
                    <link
                        rel='preload'
                        href='/api/booksy-images'
                        as='fetcherGallery'
                        crossOrigin='anonymous'
                    />
```

I have had 0 problems with using the two in tandem, which I have been for about a month now, and actually incorporating SWR into the mix *enhanced* DX/UX and next analytics reflected that (it cut FCP time by over 50% to 0.4 seconds, LCP to around 0.8 seconds).

Comment: if you're looking to useSWR as an extension of apolloClient, like fetching data for it, then I'd say so. I am about to incorporate SWR on the client in this repo to cache `getServerSideProps` data if you want to check it out. should do it sometime in the next day. https://github.com/DopamineDriven/github-search-graphql

Check out `pages/repos/[login].tsx` and `pages/repos/[login]/[details].tsx`

Answer (score 1):

There is a comparison: [Comparison | React Query vs SWR vs Apollo vs RTK Query](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/blob/69d88cca55915a1830d66465289ecc2a6e83329f/docs/src/pages/comparison.md)

Comment: nothing about the question ...  errors in table (rest link, retry link, 'lagged query' can be easily done)